# VBA code to input in cell depending on if a cell in a different sheet has a formula

Tags: vba, excel

I am hoping someone here can help me. I am trying to create a macro that looks at a cell in one sheet to see if that cell has a formula or not. If it has a formula it inputs a 1 in the same cell on a different sheet, if not it inputs a 0. This is what I have so far but it is giving me a compile error: Next without for.

```
Sub FormulaMap()
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer

For c = 9 To 17
   For r = 11 To 18

If Sheets("Data").Cells(c & r).HasFormula = True Then
  Sheets("Map").Cells(c & r).Value = 1
  Else: Sheets("Map").Cells(c & r).Value = 0

Next r

Next c

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Nathan_Sav you need to add `End If` before calling the next `r` and `c`, you also need to use a comma to separate the `c` and `r` in the `Cells` function. I'm also assuming that `c` is a column reference and `r` is a row reference? Try this:

```
Sub FormulaMap()

   Dim r As Long
   Dim c As Long

   For c = 9 To 17
      For r = 11 To 18

         If Sheets("Data").Cells(r, c).HasFormula Then
            Sheets("Map").Cells(r, c).Value = 1
         Else
            Sheets("Map").Cells(r, c).Value = 0
         End If

      Next r
   Next c

End Sub
```

Also note that the VBA Integer type only ranges from -32,768 to 32,767. This is why it's recommended to use Long (–2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647) especially when going through rows.

Answer (score 0):

You have no `End If` at the end of your `If Then Else`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is what Nathan_Sav said, but second thing is that you have to change your `Cells` statements so there are two arguments inside. The proper way to call it is

```
Cells(row, column)
```

So in your code it would be

```
Cells(r, c)
```

(if `r` means row and `c` - column)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be

```
   For c = 9 To 17
   For r = 11 To 18

      If Sheets("Data").Cells(c, r).HasFormula = True Then
        Sheets("Map").Cells(c, r).Value = 1
      Else
        Sheets("Map").Cells(c, r).Value = 0
      End If


    Next r

    Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could try this method...
You can pass in different ranges...

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

   Dim ws As Worksheet 'Reference the Map sheet
   Dim rData As Range 'Reference the actual range
   Set ws = Worksheets("Map")
   Set rData = Sheets("Data").Range("I11:Q18") 'Can be any range.

   'Do the call..
   Call EnumFormulas(rData, ws)

End Sub

Public Sub EnumFormulas(ByVal SourceData As Range, ByVal Destination As Worksheet)

   Dim rFoundFormulas As Range, rPtr As Range

   'Fill all data to 0's
   Destination.Range(SourceData.Address).Value = 0

   On Error Resume Next
   Set rFoundFormulas = SourceData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
   On Error GoTo 0

   If Not rFoundFormulas Is Nothing Then
     For Each rPtr In rFoundFormulas
         Destination.Range(rPtr.Address).Value = 1 'Fill in 1 cell.
     Next
   End If

End Sub
```